# How to create multiple transitions on a single view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

Is it possible to implement [draggable panel](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel/blob/develop/art/screenshot4.gif)! 
using motion layout?

I have tried to play around the google sample of youtube like transition by using multiple Transitions with OnSwipe on a single view but not able to succeed. Can anyone please guide me to implement how to apply the two transitions using OnSwipe on the same view?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/expanded"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/collapsed"
        app:duration="100"
        app:interpolator="easeInOut">

        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:maxAcceleration="200"
            app:touchAnchorId="@+id/videoViewContainer"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top" />


        <KeyFrameSet>
            <!--<KeyAttribute-->
                <!--app:framePosition="0"-->
                <!--app:target="@id/videoView">-->
                <!--<CustomAttribute-->
                    <!--app:attributeName="EndPadding"-->
                    <!--app:customDimension="@dimen/video_view_right_padding" />-->
            <!--</KeyAttribute>-->

            <!--<KeyAttribute-->
                <!--app:framePosition="20"-->
                <!--app:target="@id/videoView">-->
                <!--<CustomAttribute-->
                    <!--app:attributeName="EndPadding"-->
                    <!--app:customDimension="0dp" />-->
            <!--</KeyAttribute>-->

            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="0"
                app:target="@id/videoMotionLayout">
                <CustomAttribute
                    app:attributeName="height"
                    app:customDimension="90dp" />
            </KeyAttribute>

            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="20"
                app:target="@id/videoMotionLayout">
                <CustomAttribute
                    app:attributeName="height"
                    app:customDimension="250dp" />
            </KeyAttribute>

            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="0"
                app:target="@id/videoMotionLayout">
                <CustomAttribute
                    app:attributeName="width"
                    app:customDimension="160dp" />
            </KeyAttribute>

            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="20"
                app:target="@id/videoMotionLayout">
                <CustomAttribute
                    app:attributeName="width"
                    app:customDimension="0dp" />
            </KeyAttribute>

            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                app:framePosition="0"
                app:target="@id/videoRecyclerView" />

            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="1"
                app:framePosition="100"
                app:target="@id/videoRecyclerView" />

            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="0"
                app:target="@id/videoViewContainer">
                <CustomAttribute
                    app:attributeName="cardElevation"
                    app:customDimension="5dp" />
            </KeyAttribute>

            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="3"
                app:target="@id/videoViewContainer">
                <CustomAttribute
                    app:attributeName="cardElevation"
                    app:customDimension="0dp" />
            </KeyAttribute>

        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>


    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/close"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/close"
        app:duration="100"
        app:interpolator="easeInOut">

        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragLeft"
            app:maxAcceleration="200"
            app:touchAnchorId="@+id/videoViewContainer"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top" />


        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyAttribute
                app:framePosition="0"
                app:target="@id/videoMotionLayout">
            </KeyAttribute>
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/close"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/close"
        app:duration="100"
        app:interpolator="easeInOut">

        <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragRight"
            app:maxAcceleration="200"
            app:touchAnchorId="@+id/videoViewContainer"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top" />


        <KeyFrameSet>

        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/close">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/videoViewContainer"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/videoViewContainer" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/collapsed">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/videoViewContainer"
            android:layout_height="113dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="-1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/videoViewContainer" />

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

It would be helpful If I can move the mini-player scene to the left and right directions as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to create multiple transitions on a single view

It is possible to add multiple transitions to the same View. For example we can define animations with  `motion:dragDirection="dragDown"` and   `motion:dragDirection="dragUp"` on the same `touchAnchorId`  without any problem. The possible configurations are given below,

```
  motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
  motion:dragDirection="dragDown"
  motion:dragDirection="dragLeft"
  motion:dragDirection="dragRight"
```

### What to do

So, here I show you how to implement all these together on the same View.
Before writing any code, please see the below gif to better understand what we are trying to create.

[image: gif image showing multi transition example]

### How to do

**Add the `ConstraintLayout` dependency:**

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
 }
```

**Create a MotionLayout file:**

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    motion:layoutDescription="@xml/motionscene1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:background="#453672"
        motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

**Create a MotionScene:**
A MotionScene is an XML resource file that contains all of the motion descriptions for the corresponding layout. Put the file under **res/xml/** folder

*motionscene1.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- top to bottom right-->
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/step2"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/step1"

        motion:duration="500">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragDown"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/image"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top" />
    </Transition>
    <!-- bottom right to bottom left-->
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/step3"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/step2"

        motion:duration="500">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragLeft"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/image"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="left" />
    </Transition>

    <!-- bottom left to top-->
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/step1"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/step3"

        motion:duration="500">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/image"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top" />
    </Transition>
    <!-- bottom right to top-->
    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/step1"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/step2"

        motion:duration="500">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/image"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top" />
    </Transition>
    <!-- place the view on top-->
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/step1">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <PropertySet android:alpha="1" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
    <!-- place the view on bottom right-->
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/step2">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/image"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
            <PropertySet android:alpha="1" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
    <!-- place the view on bottom left-->
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/step3">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/image"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
            <PropertySet android:alpha="1" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>


</MotionScene>
```

That's all. You created an amazing custom animation with out writing any java/kotlin code. MotionLayout is fully declarative, meaning that you can describe any transitions in XML, no matter how complex.

Comment: Hi @Darish, Is the above code tested? I mean adding multiple transitions doesn't seem to be working. Can you please check and confirm.

Comment: @srikanth31 what issue you are facing? I checked and created that gif image myself. You can also verify it by simply creating an Activity with the above snippets as layout files.

Comment: dragDirection is happening in reverse direction and vice versa and swipe left to right is not happening.

Comment: did you try the above snippet just as it is? could you please check? if that works, then definitely in your own code something must be missing.